# obtaining a semantic network based on a Quanteda feature co-occurrence (fcm) matrix

Tags: quanteda

I employed the code on this page datahttps://tutorials.quanteda.io/basic-operations/fcm/fcm/ using my data, however, the plot didn't feature any connections between the points. While it is possible there were no connections, I tried to run the code on the page, however, I obtained an error:

> corp_news <- download('data_corpus_guardian')
>   Error in download("data_corpus_guardian") : 
>     could not find function "download"

I have three questions:

1. how can I access data_corpus_guardian ?
2. is there an alternative dataset to try? I tried: data_char_ukimmig2010, but obtained  a message:

   > topfeatures(dfmat_news)
   >   numeric(0)
3. what is the input for the plot? How can this be inspected so I can check, if there is connection between any tokens?

Any assistance is appreciated,

Bob

Comment: In replicating https://tutorials.quanteda.io/basic-operations/fcm/fcm/, which I can verify works fine, you will need to run _all_ of the steps including `require(quanteda.corpora)` which loads the namespace containing the `download()` function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's simple user error in not following a set of tutorial instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I went through my various attempts I came across this one: > require(quanteda)
> require(quanteda.corpora)
Loading required package: quanteda.corpora
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘quanteda.corpora’                                                                           
No doubt it is a simple error. What should I be doing? I believe I copied the code from the web-page.

Comment: See the installation instructions at https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.corpora.

Comment: Many thanks. > require(quanteda)
> require(quanteda.corpora)
Loading required package: quanteda.corpora

Attaching package: ‘quanteda.corpora’

The following object is masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

    download                                                                                                      
 I'm going to have to look into this some more.  There was an earlier message: Downloading GitHub repo quanteda/quanteda.corpora@master
WARNING: Rtools 3.3 found on the path at c:/Rtools is not compatible with R 3.5.3. Is this related to this issue or another problem?

Comment: You need to update Rtools: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: A colleague suggested a solution to my problem, i.e., that the plot didn't feature any connections between data points (tokens).  Instead of the R console, she employed RStudio and suggested the zoom function. Zoom facilitated the display of the connections between tokens.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are not proficient in `R` but still want to learn, one solution that works is:

```
library(devtools)

devtools::install_github("quanteda/quanteda.corpora")


require(quanteda) 

require(quanteda.corpora)


corp_news <- download('data_corpus_guardian')
```